# reflectbox interferes with tikz-cd's automatic resizing

Tags: tikz-cd, adjustbox

The Japanese character "yo", よ, is often used to denote the Yoneda embedding in category theory. Wanting to denote a related operator with the horizontally reflected character, I created a macro employing the `\reflectbox` command from the `adjustbox` package. Meanwhile, I am using `tikz-cd` to format commutative diagrams. Normally, `tikz-cd` resizes labels on arrows in diagrams, but reflectbox interferes with this somehow. The following MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{min}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{min}{m}{n}{<-> udmj30}{}
\newcommand{\yo}{\!\text{\usefont{U}{min}{m}{n}\symbol{'210}}\!}
\newcommand{\yoco}{\reflectbox{\yo}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    \& \cdot \\
    {\yoco(C)} \&\& {\yo(D)} \\
    {\yoco(C')} \&\& {\yo(D')} \\
    \& \cdot
    \arrow["{\yoco(f)}"'{color = red}, from=2-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow["{[x]}"{near end}, from=2-1, to=2-3]
    \arrow["{\yo(g)}", from=2-3, to=3-3]
    \arrow["{[y]}"'{near end}, from=3-1, to=3-3]
    \arrow[dotted, no head, from=1-2, to=4-2]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

produces the following diagram as output:
[image: Diagram in which the left-hand label, containing a horizontally reflected "yo" (highlighted in red for emphasis) is not properly rescaled.]

The left-hand arrow label has not resized properly, which is a problem as soon as both versions of "yo" appear as labels in a diagram. How should I modify my code to rectify this? Is it related to the choice of document style (`amsart`)?

Comment: not that it matters but `\reflectbox` comes from graphicx package

Comment: I think the label is scriptsize, you may want `\text{\reflectbox...` so the ams `\text` macro chooses teh right size, as you did in `\yo`

Comment: That fixes it right away, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify the example to

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[
a^{\text{F}} + a^{\reflectbox{F}} + a^{\text{\reflectbox{F}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

`\reflectbox` acts like `\mbox` and prevents things getting smaller in scriptstyle. The `amsmath` macro `\text` sets such boxes at a suitable size in script and scriptscript styles, as shown in the third term above.

So the difference between your definitions was the use or not of `\text` and adding `\text` produces the result you expected.

```
\newcommand{\yoco}{\text{\reflectbox{\yo}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

When `\text` is inside `\reflectbox` it's already in text mode, so it is the same as `\mbox` and doesn't scale.

I suggest to split the definition, for efficiency.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{min}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{min}{m}{n}{<-> udmj30}{}
\newcommand{\yochar}{\usefont{U}{min}{m}{n}\symbol{'210}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\yo}{}{\!\text{\yochar}\!}
\NewDocumentCommand{\yoco}{}{\!\text{\reflectbox{\yochar}}\!}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    & \cdot \\
    {\yoco(C)} && {\yo(D)} \\
    {\yoco(C')} && {\yo(D')} \\
    & \cdot
    \arrow["{\yoco(f)}"'{color = red}, from=2-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow["{[x]}"{near end}, from=2-1, to=2-3]
    \arrow["{\yo(g)}", from=2-3, to=3-3]
    \arrow["{[y]}"'{near end}, from=3-1, to=3-3]
    \arrow[dotted, no head, from=1-2, to=4-2]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

With `\NewDocumentCommand` you won't worry about the commands appearing in “risky” contexts.

[image]