# Arrow Label Size Issue in Tikz-CD

Tags: fontsize, tikz-cd, mathtools

I am using the `mathtools` package in combination with the `tikz-cd` package to decorate an arrow label with an overbracket. However, using the `\overbracket` within the arrow labeling messes up the automatic vertical-height adjustment of `tikz-cd`.

[image]

The above comes from the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-cd,mathtools}

\newcommand{\CompB}[1]{\overbracket[.5pt][1pt]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\CompB{M} \ar[rr,"{\CompB{f}}" near start]\ar[rr,"\overbracket{f}"]\ar[rr,"f" near end] && N
\\
& M \ar[ul,"b"]\ar[ur,swap,"f"] &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

In included two labels for the upper arrow to highlight the problem (and to test whether the problem is my slight redefinition of the overbracket). I was not able to get something helpful out of the [tikz-cd documentation](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf), but I might have overlooked something.

> How can I readjust the height of `\overbracket{f}` in the `tikz-cd` arrow label correctly? And why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701928/reflectbox-interferes-with-tikz-cds-automatic-resizing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `\overbracket` puts the contents in a box, forgetting the style on the outside. So you need to capture the external math style and place it inside the box. There are several ways to do this, the easiest possibly being to use the `scalerel` package with its `\ThisStyle` and `\SavedStyle` commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-cd,mathtools,scalerel}

\newcommand{\CompB}[1]{\ThisStyle{\overbracket[.5pt][1pt]{\SavedStyle{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\CompB{M} \ar[rr,"{\CompB{f}}"] && N \\
& M \ar[ul,"b"]\ar[ur,swap,"f"] &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very elegant! It does not seem to create problems elsewhere (in fact, it fixed a different slight problem which just came up).

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty hack:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-cd,mathtools}

\newcommand{\CompB}[1]{\overbracket[.5pt][1pt]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\CompB{M} \ar[rr,"\text{$\CompB{f}$}" near start]\ar[rr,"\text{$\overbracket{f}$}"]\ar[rr,"f" near end] && N
\\
& M \ar[ul,"b"]\ar[ur,swap,"f"] &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. (+1) Maybe better to put it into the macro? `\newcommand{\CompB}[1]{\text{$\overbracket[.5pt][1pt]{#1}$}}`

Comment: @SandyG I don't think this would be a good idea in case the users also uses the macro elsewhere

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The macro is used throughout the document I am writing, not just in the diagram. Thanks for the solution (although this feels dirty :D).

Comment: @mrtaurho Oh, it does not only *feel* dirty, it *is* dirty :)

Answer (score 3):

Teach `\CompB` to preserve the current math style, using `\mathpalette`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\CompB}{m}{{% the inner braces are important
  \mathpalette\CompB@{#1}%
}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\CompB@}{mm}{\overbracket[0.4pt][1pt]{#1#2}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\CompB{M} \ar[rr,"\CompB{f}"] && N
\\
& M \ar[ul,"b"]\ar[ur,swap,"f"] &
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]